# array initialise and putting value into array and looping it

Tags: php, mysql

i have a query which checks the user-count and application-count from two different tables in mysql with multiple time-range.

the query which i use to fetch record from two tables with different time-range is huge and static.the report generated like this

```
Time                  count Logged In user    Count-Apps
5.30-6.30 PM            2                      3
6.31-7.30 PM            4                      1
7.31 - 8.30 PM          3                      2
8.31-9.30 PM            5                      7
9.31-10.30 PM           2                      2
10.31-11.30 PM          3                      4
11.31- 12.30 PM         5                      5
```

my `script.php`

```
<?php

$query=mysql_query("SELECT sub0.TimeRange, sub0.number, COUNT(*) AS countapps
FROM
(
SELECT 
    CASE

        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '05:30:00' and '06:30:00'
            THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '05:30:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '06:31:00' and '07:30:00'
            THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '06:31:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '07:31:00' and '08:30:00'
            THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '07:31:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '08:31:00' and '09:30:00'
            THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '08:31:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '09:31:00' and '10:30:00'
            THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '09:31:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')   
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '10:31:00' and '11:30:00'
            THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '10:31:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')   
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '11:31:00' and '12:30:00'
            THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '11:31:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')


        ELSE NULL
    END AS StartRange,
    CASE

        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '05:30:00' and '06:30:00'
            THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '06:30:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '06:31:00' and '07:30:00'
            THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '07:30:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '07:31:00' and '08:30:00'
            THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '08:30:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '08:31:00' and '09:30:00'
            THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '09:30:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')   
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '09:31:00' and '10:30:00'
            THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '10:30:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')   
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '10:31:00' and '11:30:00'
            THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '11:30:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '11:31:00' and '12:30:00'
            THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '12:30:00'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')

        ELSE NULL
    END AS EndRange,
    CASE

        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '05:30:00' and '06:30:00'
            THEN '05:30:00-06:30:00'
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '06:31:00' and '07:30:00'
            THEN '06:31:00-07:30:00'
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '07:31:00' and '08:30:00'
            THEN '07:31:00-08:30:00'
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '08:31:00' and '09:30:00'
            THEN '08:31:00-09:30:00'    
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '09:31:00' and '10:30:00'
            THEN '09:31:00-10:30:00'    
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '10:31:00' and '11:30:00'
            THEN '10:31:00-11:30:00'    
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '11:31:00' and '12:30:00'
            THEN '11:31:00-12:30:00'


        ELSE NULL
    END AS TimeRange,
    COUNT(*) as number
FROM report
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y:%m:%d')=DATE(CURDATE())
GROUP BY StartRange, EndRange, TimeRange
HAVING TimeRange IS NOT NULL
) sub0
LEFT OUTER JOIN report1 
ON  report1.dt  BETWEEN sub0.StartRange AND sub0.EndRange
GROUP BY sub0.TimeRange, sub0.number");

echo'<html>
<head>
<title>Count User Info TimeWise</title>
</head>
<h1>Count User</h1>
<table border="3" cellspacing="2">

<tr>
<th>range</th>
<th>count</th>
<th>Apps Count</th>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
echo  "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['TimeRange'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['number'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['countapps'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";      
echo "</html>";
```

In the above query its joining two tables  `report` and `report1` and its working fine but its not a conventional way of doing it,because in future if the time range gets added i have to add again extra lines for it and the query will get even more bigger.

how can i make it dynamic by taking an array and putting all the values there then loop it and run sql.

Comment: why `date_format(dt, '...')` to convert a mysql date into a string, which then forces mysql to convert that BACK to a time value? why not just `time(dt)`?

Comment: yes@MarcB the table column `dt`datatype as datetime.for checking with currentdate also.i havent used time(dt) and yes maybe it will also work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build up the query with PHP:

```
$time_ranges = array(
        array('05:30:00', '06:30:00'),
        array('06:31:00', '07:30:00'),
        array('07:31:00', '08:30:00'),
        array('08:31:00', '09:30:00'),
        array('09:31:00', '10:30:00'),
        array('10:31:00', '11:30:00'),
        array('11:31:00', '12:30:00'),
);

$sql="SELECT sub0.TimeRange, sub0.number, COUNT(*) AS countapps
FROM
(
SELECT 
    CASE
";

foreach ($time_ranges as $r) {
    $sql .= "
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '$r[0]' and '$r[1]'
           THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '$r[0]'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') ";
}


$sql .= "
        ELSE NULL
    END AS StartRange,
    CASE ";

foreach ($time_ranges as $r) {
    $sql .= "
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '$r[0]' and '$r[1]'
            THEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', '$r[1]'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') ";
}

$sql .= "
        ELSE NULL
    END AS EndRange,
    CASE ";

foreach ($time_ranges as $r) {
    $sql .= "
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '$r[0]' and '$r[1]'
            THEN '$r[0]-$r[1]' ";
}

$sql .= "
        ELSE NULL
    END AS TimeRange,
    COUNT(*) as number
FROM report
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y:%m:%d')=DATE(CURDATE())
GROUP BY StartRange, EndRange, TimeRange
HAVING TimeRange IS NOT NULL
) sub0
LEFT OUTER JOIN report1 
ON  report1.dt  BETWEEN sub0.StartRange AND sub0.EndRange
GROUP BY sub0.TimeRange, sub0.number";

$query=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: i tried your code but the Count-apps showing 1 values in all row and not the exact count from `report1` table though there is more count between a single time range

Comment: @hitlooser, oops, in the 2nd foreach, I should have used `$r[1]` instead of `$r[0]`.